# Consistent space between text for figures, tables, etc. (floats)

Tags: spacing, floats, captions, floatrow

Assuming I am using an `[H]` float, I'd like to create equal space above the caption, and below the table (for a table with caption above), and that same space above a figure, and below the caption (for a figure with caption below). Additionally, I'd like the spacing between the caption and table or figure to be the same. I thought this would be easy with the `caption` package, but I am struggling.

How would you do it? I'd like to avoid patching my floats with `vspace` etc. as it might mess things up on a float page.

The space under the table, and caption of figure, are clearly larger than the specified amount, and the distance above is noticeable smaller. Also, the `skip` setting in `caption` doesn't seem to do anything with `floatrow`, although the documentation says it should cooperate.

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{printlen}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[%
skip=1  0pt,
]{caption} %

\usepackage{floatrow} 

\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\floatsetup[figure]{capposition=bottom}


\newlength{\parskiplength}
\setlength{\parskiplength}{13.6pt}

\setlength{\floatsep}{\parskiplength}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{\parskiplength}
\setlength{\intextsep}{\parskiplength}

\captionsetup{belowskip=0pt}
\captionsetup{aboveskip=0pt}


\newcommand{\blah}{Here is some text. Blah blah  blah  blah  blah  blah  blah  blah  blah  blah  blah  blah  blah  blah  blah  blah  blah  blah  blah  blah  blah.}

\begin{document}

    parskip:\uselengthunit{pt}\printlength{\parskip}\\
    baselineskip:\uselengthunit{pt}\printlength{\baselineskip}\\


\section{A figure}

\blah

\blah

\begin{figure}[H]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{A caption}
\end{figure}

\blah

\newpage

\section{A table}

\blah

\begin{table}[H]
    \caption{A caption}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \toprule
        Alpha & Beta \\
        Gamma & Delta \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\blah

\end{document}
```

Comment: H makes the environment nota float so your comment about float pages seems mis-placed, an H enviornment will never be on a float page.

Comment: Ah; very good point. Would you recommend using the center environment instead then, if I absolutely need an H "float"?

Answer (score 1):

Below the duck you have

```
...\glue 13.6
...\glue(\parskip) 13.6 plus 1.36008
...\glue(\baselineskip) 5.99585
...\hbox(7.60416+0.0)x418.25555, glue set 0.38042
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 H
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 e
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 r
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 e
```

so both `\intextsep` (13.6pt) and `\parskip` (13.6pt plus 1.36008pt) and the baselineskip to the next line of text `Here....`

Comment: So how do I prevent that?

Comment: @likethevegetable set `\intextsep` to 0pt and rely on `\parskip` space?

Comment: how did you produce that output? The `\glue 13.6` etc. etc. I'm assuming that's the primitive TeX output? I feel like seeing that would really help me learn.

Comment: @likethevegetable `\showoutput`